# Swift 3 Xcode8 - How to instantiate different View on button Action

Tags: ios, swift, xib

sorry if my question is stupid but I'm new of iOS programming, I have a view controller with 2 button and a view(not full screen), I need to change the content of view on button action, the first view have a table controller and the second one a gallery.
can I use view or I need to change the component?
I saw the viewpagecontroller but I can't find anything for the use of them inside view controller.
thanks.

Screenshot:
https://ibb.co/gzr9qv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a easy way to meet your request. You can just put View1 and View2 both in the content view, and first set View2 hidden. 
Then if action1, you set View1 is not hidden, and View2 is hidden,
if action2, set View1 is hidden, and View2 is not hidden.

Comment: and can I auto layout both views without problems?

Comment: You can use auto layout both with view1 and view2, but do Not add any constrains between with View1 and View2, you can add auto layout between View1 and content view, View 2 and content view. If you hidden view1 or view2, it will not affect the other one.